# Scheme: All Possible Shifts from Front of List to Back

Tags: scheme, racket

I need to write a Scheme function that takes a list as an argument and returns a list of lists where every list is a cycle of the original list. 
By a cycle, I mean shifting the first element to the last position.
I have the following functions:

```
(define (cycle lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((null? (cdr lst)) lst)
        (else (append (cdr lst) (list (car lst)))))) 

(define (shift lst)
  (define (iter l cycles result)
    (cond ((= cycles 0) (cons lst result))
          ((< cycles 1) result)
          (else (iter (cycle-1 l) (- cycles 1) (cons result (cycle-1 l))))))
  (iter lst (- (length lst) 1) '()))
```

Now, when I do:
(shift '(1 2 3))
I get:
'((1 2 3) (() 2 3 1) 3 1 2)
I should get:
'((1 2 3) (2 3 1) (3 1 2))

Comment: `cycle-1`s in `shift` function should be `cycle` in this code to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define (shift lst)
  (define (iter l cycles result)
    (cond ((= cycles 0)
           (cons lst result))
          ((< cycles 0) result)
          (else (let ((cycled (cycle l)))
                  (iter cycled (- cycles 1) (cons cycled result))))))
  (iter lst (- (length lst) 1) '()))
```

First, I've made a simple improvement to prevent calculate cycled form of the list twice(added `let`). Second, you need to cons `cycled` to `result` since you need to append `result` list, not `cycled` list. In your code, you're adding last result to old results and then passing this wrongly appended results list to `iter` functions as `result` parameter.

Update: To get the results in your order you can simple just append result with cycled list, instead of adding cycled list to head of the result:

```
(define (shift lst)
  (define (iter l cycles result)
    (cond ((= cycles 0)
           (cons lst result))
          ((< cycles 0) result)
          (else (let ((cycled (cycle l)))
                  (iter cycled (- cycles 1) (append result (list cycled)))))))
  (iter lst (- (length lst) 1) '()))
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much.
Just a nitpick though. I am getting 
'((1 2 3) (3 1 2) (2 3 1))
I was wondering if it was possible to get:
'((1 2 3) (2 1 3) (3 1 2)) 
?